# Омонимы ли "партнёрки"?

Tags: сокращения, омонимы, корень-слова

Являются ли омонимами партнёрка (ж. р. от "партнёр") и партнёрка (сокращение от "партнёрская программа")? Возможны ли вообще омонимы от однокоренных слов при том, что они пишутся и звучат идентично?

Comment: Партнёрка (ж. р. от "партнёр")? Есть ссылка?

Comment: Не "партнёрка", а "партнёрша".

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не добавлять морфемы, обозначающие женский род, ко всем подряд словам (партнерка, писательница, режиссерша и т.д.), так как для носителя это звучит не лучшим образом. Такую подходящую морфему должны подобрать лингвисты, а потом навязать её использование, как это было с ‟поэтесса”. Если уж представить, что ‟партнерка” является литературной нормой, обозначая лицо женского рода, то это был бы омоформ, то есть слово, которое только в какой-то одной форме совпадает с другим словом в какой-то одной форме.